# Why are the language bar buttons locked / pressed?

Tags: windows-7, input-languages, ime

I'm using the Language Bar in Windows 7 to switch between English and Japanese. In 'Japanese' mode the bar has a few extra buttons for switching between the various alphabets / width styles - image 1:

[image: JP language bar - buttons clickable]

However, occasionally the buttons switch to a state where they are seemingly 'locked', i.e. they can't be pressed or changed (image 2)

[image]

I have no idea why this happens, and it prevents me from switching between the alphabets I require. What causes this?

Comment: I know think it has something to do with whether you are currently in an editable area (browser bar, text field, Word doc) but a proper explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for - [The Language bar (overview)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/The-Language-bar-overview)

> The set of buttons and options on the Language bar changes depending
>   on the text services you have installed and the software program
>   that's currently active. For example, WordPad supports speech
>   recognition, but Notepad does not. If both programs are running, the
>   speech buttons appear when WordPad is active, but disappear when you
>   make Notepad the active program.